# Why are some journals for research papers called “review”?

Tags: journals, terminology, academic-history

There are many journals from different fields feature the word *review* in their name even though they are mostly featuring research articles – and not review articles, book reviews or similar. Some do not even accept review articles at all.
Some examples are
[the *Physical Review* series](http://journals.aps.org/about),
[*Geographical Review*](http://americangeo.org/geographical-review/),
[*Drug and Alcohol Review*](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/(ISSN)1465-3362/homepage/ProductInformation.html),
[*Victorian Periodicals Review*](http://www.press.jhu.edu/journals/victorian_periodicals_review/), and
[*The Linguistic Review*](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/tlir).

The only thing in this journal that is somehow connected to *review* is the peer-review and the consequential revision of the articles, but if this feature were eponymous, I would expect names like *Physical Review**ed**.*

The very sparse information about the history of these journals reveiled nothing about the motivation for naming them such, and neither did dictionaries. For example, from [Merriam–Webster’s definitions of review](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/review):

> […]
>
> 3 : a general survey (as of the events of a period)
>
> 4 : an act or the process of reviewing
>
> […]
>
> 6 a : a critical evaluation (as of a book or play)
>      b :  a magazine devoted chiefly to reviews and essays
>
> 7 a : a retrospective view or survey (as of one's life)
>      b (1) : renewed study of material previously studied (2) : an exercise facilitating such study
>
> […]

None of these fits the aforementioned journals. They aren’t surveys, evaluations, devoted to reviews and essays, retrospective or renewed studies, nor do they contain them.

**Why are these journals called *review?***

Comment: My guess is that it might be "review" in the sense of "what has happened since the last issue", I.e. an overview on what is new

Comment: This is perhaps more germane in [HSM](http://hsm.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Among the various meaning of *review*, the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/review) reports (2.1):

> [OFTEN IN NAMES] A periodical publication with critical articles on culture and current events: 
>   'the New Left Review'

A similar definition can be also found in the Random House Webster's, 2nd ed., (on paper):

> A periodical publication containing articles on current events or affairs, books, art, etc.

The above definitions do not seem to imply journals publishing only review papers in the common scientific sense.

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=review&allowed_in_frame=0) yields for review (bold mine):

> mid-15c., "an inspection of military forces," from Middle French reveue "a reviewing, review," noun use of fem. past participle of reveeir "to see again, go to see again," from Latin revidere, from re- "again" (see re-) + videre "to see" (see vision). Sense of "process of going over again" is from 1560s; that of "a view of the past, a retrospective survey" is from c. 1600. **Meaning "general examination or criticism of a recent work" is first attested 1640s.**

I think that journal papers can be considered "examinations of a recent work", that is, a review in the sense highlighted above.

It is worth noting that this usage of the noun *review* to denote a periodical publication is widespread also in other languages: in French, with the word [*revue*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/revue/69183), and in Italian with the word [*rivista*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rivista/). The note at the top of the last link says (lousy translation mine):

> nel sign. di «periodico» è modellato sul fr. *revue*, che a sua volta
>   ricalca l’ingl. *review*
>
> (with the meaning of "periodical", the term is modelled on the French
>   *revue* which, in turn, follows from the English *review*)

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. And note that the sense involve isn't just peculiar to English. Lots of Spanish and Italian journals have the word "revisita" in the title. Same for "revue" in french. The cognate term doesn't seem to be common in the germanic languages though, so maybe it's mainly a romance language thing?

Comment: @Shane: by chance, I've just added a note about other languages ;-)

Comment: Great minds think alike!

Comment: Interesting. In Spanish, "periodical" is "revista" (literally "review", from exactly the same Latin stem mentioned).

Comment: @shane, more to the point, many English language "journals" aren't precisely published daily.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd suspect that a "journal" was never intended to be taken as indicating the frequency of publication. I think the idea is more "the ideas of the day" meaning, the up-to-date record of what's happened in a field. I don't have any evidence for that though.